# Asynchronus HTTP Request return Value in Swift

Tags: ios, rest, swift, asynchronous

I'm dealing with a design Problem right now. I'm writing a Swift App, wich has a Storyboard with multiple ViewControllers and a Class HTTPRequests, wich performs GET and POST Requests on a RESTful Webservice.

My Problem right now is as following. From a view controller, I have to perform a a GET Request on the Webservice to fetch data. The received Data should be displayed trough this view controller on the specific view.
I see two possibilities to achieve this right now:

1. Put the Request function into the ViewController. Perform an asynchronus request and update the view in this asynchronus task as soon as data are received.
   I don't really like this approach for two reasons. First, I don't want the Request function inside the ViewController, because I need the same function in multiple ViewControllers and this leads to code duplication. Second, I don't want to update the view inside the asynchronus task.
2. Put the Request function into the HTTPRequests (Singleton) Class. Call the requests from a ViewController and get a return value back. With this value, the ViewController is able to update its view.
   I like this approach, because it's in design concerns "cleaner". My only problem is the return value. How can I return a value from an asynchronus task in Swift?
   If possible please with code examples.

Or is there a better approach than those two?

**Edit:**
Thanks to your answers and [this Blog Post](http://ios-blog.co.uk/tutorials/developing-ios8-apps-using-swift-part-3-best-practices/) I could successfully implement approach 2 with delegates.

Comment: You should use approach 2 with a delegate pattern

Comment: If you have much time enough to learn these,  I profoundly recommend to use functional-language-style "Future/Promise" or "FRP" for that purpose.

Comment: Thanks for you hints. I'm new to iOS Programming, so I have to learn how to deal with delegates. In this case I will take a look at Futures as well, I know them already a little from Java.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use a singleton, but rather you can have a separate class (model) that does all the web requests.  You can implement a protocol in the model and set you view controller to be delegates. Sorry I'm on mobile so I can't include code, but I'd be glad to add it later.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yeah some code would be nice ;)